# How to prevent panel from changing its children controls' sizes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel which is hosting a Treeview and a User Control. The panel itself is residing within a window form. When I maximize the window form, the panel size get changed automatically and the Treeview within it.

Is there a way to prevent the panel from changing the children control within it automatically?

I am using visual studio 2008 and C# language.

Thanks

Comment: Due to Your Disscussion I automatically got answer of my problem Which was totally Different from Yor problem.
Thanx Guy :-) My Problem was;
I couldn't Resize my panel in windo Form, yet I set the "Auto Size" property "True"
But when i saw Your Answer i got the idea of "Anchor" property and now My problem is Solved.
Thanx again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the TreeView .Anchor property to None. If the .Dock property has a value set it to None also. These two properties represent auto-resize features of a control relevant its parent container (which in your case is the Panel)

Comment: I set both properties to null and when I maximize the window form, all controls sizes change still.

Comment: It is very strange that If I did the same thing, which means set the dock and anchor to null to panel, when I maximize the window form, the panel size remains the same, BUT, the Treeview and User Control within the panel changes their size?!

Comment: Can you copy & paste into this discussion the generated Form code from the  *.Designer.cs or *.Designer.vb file of the form.

Comment: I kind of know what's wrong. These two control was originally added on the window form directly. Then I added a panel to the window form and added these two control inside the panel. I just tested added a brand new Treeview to panel, it's size remain unchanged. I am comparing the properties of the new Treeview and the old one to see if I can find something.